# Login module issue in DNN 7.0.3 and Safari

Tags: safari, dotnetnuke

I'm using DNN 7.0.3 to develop my site. The login page works fine in every navigator excepts Safari.

When I login with safari, after push login button, the page reloads again and the registration is not done.

I'm having no error messages from DNN, just reloads the page.

Everything is installed by default in DNN.

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I've tried to add a P3P customheader in web.config file. But is not working.

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        <add name="P3P" value="CP=&quot;IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT&quot;" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```

Any idea which I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is your Safari browser blocking cookies?

Comment: Thanks a lot! this was the problem. I've configured the safari to block cookies from publicity and third party. But now the question is how I can configure the DNN in order to loggin without final user has to reconfigure their safari navigator?